# Is there any way to make the name of each column take the value of a dropdown? In Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have 3 columns and 3 rows. Rows names are "1st dimension", "2nd dimension" and "3rd dimension". Columns names are "Year", "Month" and "Measure names".

For each dimension, there are several values that the user can choose such as Segment, Channel...

I'd like to know if there's any way that the name of the column could be the same as the choice from the dropdown. For example, instead of "1st dimension" -> "Channel".

I've tried using parameters but I could only change the title, not the column name.